# Cardano is leaving Beta

Tags: discussion

Today [we are leaving the Public Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375889/cardano-is-leaving-beta) of the Stack Exchange.

Good job everyone. Keep it up by posting questions and most importantly, answers.

Comment: Everyone here from 0 reputation to the top has made this possible.  Well done all!

Comment: Announced on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/cardano/comments/sjmjsh/congratulations_we_have_officially_left_public/